# Weird encoding in vtt file--python

Tags: python, encoding, webvtt

I am trying to obtain text from a subtitles file (vtt format) as follows:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://nogeovod-fy.atresmedia.com/vsg/sitemap/assets4/2022/09/26/C302281D-5C76-4710-A4FB-9AD7252B7F47/es.vtt')
print(r.encoding)

r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding

print(r.text)
```

Some characters seem to be missed as the original encoding ISO-8859-1 is not the right one. However, when I try to change it to utf-8, still all the accents remain weird...

Comment: We have no idea what you think the contents of that file should represent or what "vtt" (let alone "vpp") is supposed to stand for.  Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors explains how to ask questions about character encodings. See also https://tripleee.github.io/8bit for figuring it out yourself.

Comment: That URL does *NOT* return any encoding, so `r.encoding` is just a guess. Almost all web sites use UTF8, including Stack Overflow, and that page seems to contain some mangled UTF8 bytes

Comment: @tripleee the OP probably doesn't know about HTTP headers, charset or how some sites may omit the character set. And in this case `requests` reports the wrong encoding - there's no encoding specified

Comment: The file appears to contain valid UTF-8 but with some random [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). For example, "Unión" is represented as "UniŠn". https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#97 suggests that it was incorrectly converted from cp775 or cp852 if the real encoding was ISO-8859-1. If you explore more data points you can probably decide which of these two.

Comment: Thanks for the information and sorry about the misleading title. That file is supposed to contain spanish subtitles in vtt format. Do you believe that there is a (simple) way to get rid of the weird characters? I can imagine creating fancy dictionaries with python and a speech correction but that seems pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Actually, on closer examination, cp852 is wrong too; I can find no encoding where U+0160 (Š) and U+00F3 (ó) coincide. So you'll probably need to build a translation table yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file appears to contain the following replaced characters:

- Ć for á
- Ž for é
- Ð for í
- Š for ó
- ž for ñ
- ë for ú
- Č for ¡
- č for ¿

With that, simply replacing these one-to-one should fix your problem.  We still don't know which encoding this is, but the damage is quite limited.

```
fixed = r.text.replace("Ć", "á").replace("Ž", "é").replace(
  "Ð", "í").replace("Š", "ó").replace("ž", "ñ").replace(
  "ë", "ú").replace("Č", "¡").replace("č", "¿")
```

Comment: That should be `r.content.decode("utf-8").replace(...)`, not `r.text.replace(...)`, as Requests is guessing the wrong encoding.

Comment: (At least in my installation...)

Comment: @JackTaylor The file I downloaded is proper UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, the file is valid UTF-8, but `r.text` tries to decode it as ISO-8859-1 on my system, giving phrases like `la UniÅ\xa0n Europea`. To decode it correctly I have to explicitly specify that the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: An alternative to using `r.content.decode` would be to set `r.encoding = "utf-8"` before accessing `r.text`.